# BASH: My variable's value is not displaying correctly inside a loop

Tags: bash, variables, while-loop, jq

In the function below, I'm using JQ to parse the JSON data and get the **httpOperations** key/value pair.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
function batch_post() {
  SETTINGS_INPUT=$1 #! Variable that holds the argument value
  n=0
  :> "${SETTINGS_INPUT}"_req.tmp #! This will just create an empty file
  
  while read setting
  do
    # Get parameters that need to go in the batch put/post request
    url=$(echo $setting | ./jq -r '.url')
    body=$(echo $setting | ./jq -r '.response.body')

    # Get the request method
    method=$(cat settings.json | ./jq --arg URL ${url} '.settings[] | select(.pathPattern==$URL|tostring).httpOperations[] | select(.method == "PUT" or .method == "POST").method')
       
    # Save individual requests to be added to the batch request
    let n=n+1
  done <<< $(cat ${SETTINGS_INPUT} | ./jq -c '.')

  # Format individual requests in the expected batch json format
  cat "${SETTINGS_INPUT}"_req.tmp | ./jq -n '.requests |= [inputs]' > "${SETTINGS_LIST}"_batch_post_put_req
  # TODO: Validate this has the correct format and PUT/POST according to the settings
  cat "${SETTINGS_LIST}"_batch_post_put_req
  
  #! DO NOT execute API call with put/post request
}
```

and I'm passing a JSON file as my argument to this function, below is the content of the JSON file. Please note that this is not the full JSON data that I'm actually using.

```
   {
  "settings" : [ {
    "key" : "AccountingRules",
    "description" : "Accounting Rules settings",
    "context" : "Entity",
    "pathPattern" : "/accounting-rules",
    "httpOperations" : [ {
      "method" : "GET",
      "url" : "/settings/accounting-rules",
      "parameters" : [ ],
      "responseType" : {
        "$ref" : "#/definitions/AccountingRules",
        "definitions" : {
          "AccountingRules" : {
            "additionalProperties" : false,
            "type" : "object",
            "properties" : {
              "allowRevenueScheduleNegativeAmounts" : {
                "type" : "boolean"
              },
              "allowBlankAccountingCodes" : {
                "type" : "boolean"
              },
              "allowCreationInClosedPeriod" : {
                "type" : "boolean"
              },
              "allowUsageInClosedPeriod" : {
                "type" : "boolean"
              },
              "differentCurrencies" : {
                "type" : "boolean"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }, {
      "method" : "PUT",
      "url" : "/settings/accounting-rules",
      "parameters" : [ ],
      "requestType" : {
        "$ref" : "#/definitions/AccountingRules",
        "definitions" : {
          "AccountingRules" : {
            "additionalProperties" : false,
            "type" : "object",
            "properties" : {
              "allowRevenueScheduleNegativeAmounts" : {
                "type" : "boolean"
              },
              "allowBlankAccountingCodes" : {
                "type" : "boolean"
              },
              "allowCreationInClosedPeriod" : {
                "type" : "boolean"
              },
              "allowUsageInClosedPeriod" : {
                "type" : "boolean"
              },
              "differentCurrencies" : {
                "type" : "boolean"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "responseType" : {
        "$ref" : "#/definitions/AccountingRules",
        "definitions" : {
          "AccountingRules" : {
            "additionalProperties" : false,
            "type" : "object",
            "properties" : {
              "allowRevenueScheduleNegativeAmounts" : {
                "type" : "boolean"
              },
              "allowBlankAccountingCodes" : {
                "type" : "boolean"
              },
              "allowCreationInClosedPeriod" : {
                "type" : "boolean"
              },
              "allowUsageInClosedPeriod" : {
                "type" : "boolean"
              },
              "differentCurrencies" : {
                "type" : "boolean"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    } ]
  }, {
    "key" : "AgingBuckets",
    "description" : "Aging Buckets",
    "context" : "Entity",
    "pathPattern" : "/aging-buckets",
    "httpOperations" : [ {
      "method" : "GET",
      "url" : "/settings/aging-buckets",
      "parameters" : [ ],
      "responseType" : {
        "$ref" : "#/definitions/AgingBucket",
        "definitions" : {
          "Bucket" : {
            "additionalProperties" : false,
            "type" : "object",
            "properties" : {
              "name" : {
                "type" : "string",
                "maxLength" : 100
              },
              "fromDaysPastDue" : {
                "type" : "integer"
              },
              "toDaysPastDue" : {
                "type" : "integer"
              }
            },
            "required" : [ "name" ]
          },
          "AgingBucket" : {
            "additionalProperties" : false,
            "type" : "object",
            "properties" : {
              "includeNegativeInvoice" : {
                "type" : "boolean"
              },
              "buckets" : {
                "type" : "array",
                "items" : {
                  "$ref" : "#/definitions/Bucket"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    } ]
}
]}
```

And whenever I'm displaying the output for my variable named "method", the output that's being returned is stacked on top of one another. To give you an example, the issue looks like this when displaying the $method value.

```
Display method below
"PUT"
"POST"
"PUT"
"POST"
"PUT"
"POST"
"PUT"
"POST"
"PUT"
"POST"
"PUT"
"POST"
"PUT"
"PUT"
"POST"
"PUT"
"POST"
"POST"
"PUT"
"POST"
Done displaying method
```

Wherein I'm expecting the output to be just a single "PUT" or "POST" only. Also, the thing I observed that's kind of weird for me is that this issue will show up when I try to display my variable executing "$ echo ${method}" command but when I remove the curly braces it sometimes works fine.

Comment: Please paste your script at [shellcheck.net](http://www.shellcheck.net/) and try to implement the recommendations made there.

Comment: Quoting bash variables (`"${varname}"` instead of just `${varname}`) helps dealing with values containing spaces, thus often solves issues related to them.

Comment: @ilovetoask - What's the content of `settings.json`?

Answer (score 1):

I managed to make it work by replacing the single quote to double quotes in my JQ filter.

```
# Get the request method
method=$(cat settings.json | ./jq ".settings[] | select(.pathPattern==$URL|tostring).httpOperations[] | select(.method == \"PUT\" or .method == \"POST\").method")
```

I did not need to use the **--arg** option to define a JQ variable, what happened instead is I'm directly calling my bash variable and luckily it worked fine.

Comment: Are you sure this is functioning as you intend? I'm struggling to see how it could work, for a number of reasons: 1. your variable was called `url` not `URL`, 2. your variable wasn't a quoted JSON string so this would likely cause a syntax error, 3. the problem described in my answer remains. Did this require more changes than are described here?

Answer (score 0):

```
select(.pathPattern==$URL|tostring)
```

This is unlikely to be what you intend. The pipe `|` operator has lower precedence than the equality `==` operator. This filter is equivalent to:

```
select((.pathPattern==$URL)|tostring)
```

...which will work out as either of these:

```
select(true|tostring)
select(false|tostring)
```

...which will in turn be:

```
select("true")
select("false")
```

...and perhaps you can see where this is going. All strings are considered truth-like values. So these filters will actually select all the settings every time!